# How do you configure Ktor to enable JWT Authentication?

Tags: kotlin, authentication, jwt, ktor

For context, I am new to Java, Kotlin and Ktor (coming from a C# background).

I am receiving the following error from my build:

```
Exception in thread "main" io.ktor.server.application.MissingApplicationPluginException: Application plugin Authentication is not installed
```

The offending section of code is:

```
    authenticate("auth-jwt") {
        get("/hello") {
            val principal = call.principal<JWTPrincipal>()
            val username = principal!!.payload.getClaim("username").asString()
            val expiresAt = principal.expiresAt?.time?.minus(System.currentTimeMillis())
            call.respondText("Hello, $username! Token is expired at $expiresAt ms.")
        }
    }
```

It fails at the line with `authenticate`

Per the documentation, I have added the required plugins in my `build.gradle.kts` file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-core-jvm:$ktor_version")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-host-common-jvm:$ktor_version")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-content-negotiation-jvm:$ktor_version")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json-jvm:$ktor_version")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization-gson-jvm:$ktor_version")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-netty-jvm:$ktor_version")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-auth:$ktor_version")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-auth-jwt:$ktor_version")
    implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:$logback_version")
    testImplementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-test-host:$ktor_version")
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:$kotlin_version")
}
```

Here is my `configureSecurity` method (taken from the online examples):

```
fun Application.configureSecurity() {
    val secret = System.getenv("JWT_SECRET")
    val issuer = environment.config.property("jwt.issuer").getString()
    val audience = environment.config.property("jwt.audience").getString()
    val myRealm = environment.config.property("jwt.realm").getString()

    authentication {
        jwt("auth-jwt") {
            verifier(
                JWT
                    .require(Algorithm.HMAC256(secret))
                    .withAudience(audience)
                    .withIssuer(issuer)
                    .build()
            )
            validate { credential ->
                if (credential.payload.getClaim("username").asString() != "") {
                    JWTPrincipal(credential.payload)
                } else {
                    null
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have been working to fix this for the last nine hours, searching the web exhaustively, and this is my last resort.

I am using Beta 2.0 sample code created from the project creation wizard in IntelliJ IDEA.

How do you properly configure JWT auth on ktor server?

Comment: [Online docs](https://ktor.io/docs/jwt.html#install) and [example](https://github.com/ktorio/ktor-documentation/blob/main/codeSnippets/snippets/auth-jwt-hs256/src/main/kotlin/com/example/Application.kt#L27-L28) say it should be `install(Authentication) {...}` not `authentication { ... }`. For 2.0.0 it's [the same](https://ktor.io/docs/eap/jwt.html#install). Also, make sure that this call actually happens.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I also tried the install(Authentication) with the same results. I need to check to make sure it's actually being called, though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that configuration for a routing goes before the installation of the `Authentication` plugin. To fix it swap `configureRouting()` and `configureSecurity()` calls so it will look like this:

```
embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080, host = "0.0.0.0") {
    configureSecurity()
    configureRouting()
}.start(wait = true)
```

Comment: Is this insane detail missing in docs or didn't I noticed that? Hours trying to fix this and this crazy configs order matters...